# Saving SQL Queries in SharePoint

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Trying to determine if it is feasible to use SharePoint as a SQL Query development repository...

We do quite a bit of query development in SQL Server 2012 for data analysis/discovery and it would be great to be able to share valuable queries among team members without having to constantly email SQL back and forth. The email flood is just an ugly mess that we need to stop.

Ideally, it would be great to be able to save directly to SharePoint within SQL Server (File > Save > Save to SharePoint) and then allow SharePoint to do version management for the team. I know there are pretty robust tools out there for version management but we are currently just looking for something lightweight at this point and something that can be implemented quickly to test our options out.

1. Is something like this feasible (saving directly to SharePoint through SQL Server)?
2. If not feasible (or heck, if it is just a bad idea) what low cost/no cost options are there for sharing code/sql between team members? And better yet, something that we can get up and running very quickly...

Thanks in advance for your input and insight!

Answer (score 0):

Great idea, think I might make one myself.

Say you have

```
http://my.sharepoint.dom/cool_repos/sql
```

You should be able to access the same through explorer using

```
\\my.sharepoint.dom\cool_repos\sql
```